# concurrency in hierarchical filesystem databases

Tags: java, database

I am writing a small program that is a client of some protocol. I wanted this program to have a filesystem database. the main directory would contain one directory for a server that is configured, and the server directory would contain things like server settings in json and other data, this time those are certificates, not sure if certificates would be stored in separate dirs.
The question is: if it is possible, even though rare, that multiple instances of this app could access the database, and also this program can run in daemon mode multithreaded, what kinds of locks may be needed for thread and for jvm?

For example, should I use a read/write lock for inter thread synchronization + a shared or exclusive file lock? should I lock the whole database, or only the directory near the set of files I want to change, like the server directory?

Comment: The short answer is to use a real database, one that supports transactions and that has been rigorously tested. The longer answer starts with a question: what are the consequences of concurrent changes?

Comment: it seems that this case is too simple for a full database. the only thing I am storing in server dirs are certificates, private keys and small number of json files.

Comment: what do you mean by the question about consequences of concurrent changes? probably mostly things like the daemon trying to renew a certificate while someone has removed it from database, or rather while someone is trying to remove it

Comment: The minute that you use the words "multiple instances," you have to graduate to a real database.  You get all of the capabilities you're talking about here for free.  Check out SQLite; every smart phone on the planet uses it.

Comment: in this case "multiple instance" just means something like one user runs this thing in a daemon mode, and it starts renewing certificates (that's what the daemon mode would be for), and the second process removes a server. this program is generally a command line application with almost no risk of concurrent usage except concurrent renewal of certificates or accidental use possibly?

Comment: I still feel this is the time where database is too much for it. Maybe I am wrong, but I still would like to know what to do with a fs database. For example if I would place locks for a main db directory and for the server directory, would it be too much locking? like when adding a certificate, I would need a read lock/shared lock for main db directory to disallow, mostly, server deletion. and exclusive lock for server dir to disallow access when one of the certificates is being changed. like in general, locking for each level of the hierarchy to prevent things to unexpectedly disappear.

Comment: The bar for choosing a database is really low.  Why reinvent the wheel?  Unless, perhaps, this is just a useful learning exercise?

Comment: no, it is not a learning exercise. Although after some consideration I assumed that the user of my program, even when calling few instances at once, will not notice a delay if I just place one global database wide file lock, especially that I do not need to access network during locking.

Comment: in addition, I probably could write it in such a way so that thread level locks will be unneeded, as multiple threads will never modify the same file, nor the database structure.

Comment: that gives no thread locks, and one database wide shared or exclusive lock per jvm withat would also be reentrant. no such high level of concurrency, but I am not sure if users running the program from cmdline would notice it at all.